# How to create a custom button in Jodit to wrap the text in a code tag?

Tags: jodit

Basically I want to be able to generate html like `<code>{a: true}</code>`

As far as I can tell, the button should do the same thing as the "underline" button for example, except it will wrap the text in `<code>` instead of `<u>`;

I have tried using this:

```
{
    buttons:
      'bold,strikethrough,underline,italic,eraser,|,superscript,subscript,|,ul,ol,align,|,outdent,indent,|,font,fontsize,brush,paragraph,|,image,video,table,link,|,undo,redo,\n,selectall,cut,copy,paste,copyformat,|,hr,symbol,source,fullsize,print,code',

    language: lang,
    placeholder,
    toolbarAdaptive: false,
    uploader: {
      insertImageAsBase64URI: true,
    },
    controls: {
      code: {
        name: 'code',
        iconURL: 'someurl.com',
        tagRegExp: '_PxEgEr_/^(code)$/i',
        tags: ['code'],
        tooltip: 'Code',
      },
    },
  }
```

The button shows up in the toolbar, but nothing happens when I click it. The documentation shows buttons that insert text, but I need a button that wraps text instead.

Comment: Hi, perhaps add prefix/suffix text?

Comment: @IronMan Not sure what you mean prefix/suffix? This is the definition for button: https://xdsoft.net/jodit/doc/types/IControlType/ It doesn't seem to mention any prefix/suffix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I figured it after going through their code, it's not well documented, but this is how you do it:

```
{
  buttons: 'blockquote,code',
  controls: {
    code: {
      name: 'code',
      iconURL: 'someiconurl.com',
      tooltip: 'Insert Code Block',
      exec: function (editor) {
        editor.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'code');
      },
      isActive: (editor, control) => {
        const current = editor.s.current();
        return Boolean(
          current && Jodit.modules.Dom.closest(current, 'code', editor.editor)
        );
      },
    },
    blockquote: {
      name: 'blockquote',
      iconURL: 'someiconurl.com',
      tooltip: 'Insert blockqoute',
      exec: function (editor) {
        editor.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'blockquote');
      },
      isActive: (editor, control) => {
        const current = editor.s.current();
        return Boolean(
          current && Jodit.modules.Dom.closest(current, 'blockquote', editor.editor)
        );
      },
    },
  },
}
```